# How to semantically version a change to a CSS color property

Tags: css, semantic-versioning

I maintain a CSS framework and am trying to follow semantic versioning in a way that makes the most sense.
Would changing the value of non critical property (like the color of an element) be considered a minor change or a patch change?
If I am at version 0.5.0 but want to release an update with no new features just changes to some colors, should I release as 0.5.1 or 0.6.0?

While a color change won't exactly "break" a code base, I could see how to some this should be considered a minor change. But for the sole fact that this kind of change is not adding a feature is why I could also see it being just a patch change.  Hoping to learn if there is an generally accepted standard for this situation.

Comment: I'd suggest some sort of scheme (which maybe you could document) whereby e.g. brightness is patch-level, hue is minor, and 'colour' (i.e. changed the widget from red to blue) is major. That aside, I expect to see this, though interesting, closed as *primarily opinion-based*. It may fair better on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @OllieFord I figured as much, although I was banking on the idea that there might actually be a preferred method to this kind of versioning so hopefully it stays open. I'll try there if it closes

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Bootstrap adopts Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#versioning) even if I wasn't able to find how they have defined the API.

I have seen an [attempt to define a CSS API](https://medium.com/design-optimizely/how-to-version-your-ui-library-1c7a1b7ee23a) and [another one](https://github.com/primer/css/issues/241) but I'm not totally satisfied.

About colors I have always wondered about including in the API the version of a validation tool for accessibility and setting some thresholds. The thresholds are mapped to minor or patch. But it's only a raw idea.